# How can I draw a line with CoreGraphics, whose trail will begin to disappear at a certain length?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-graphics

What I'm talking about can be seen here, from starting at 1:04. After 5-10 seconds, you'll understand what I mean by "trail will begin to disappear".

My current app draws a faint and thin line was the user moves around the screen. However, that lines sticks around until `-touchesEnded:withEvent:`, when I set the `imageView.image = nil`.

What I want to achieve is a line that is actively being drawn, and as you draw the line, the oldest parts of the line will become more transparent until it eventually disappears. The line draw could either be time based, or it could be based on how long the lines length currently is.

How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know how you're currently doing this, but this is how I'd go about doing it...

1. **Create a custom object to store a small portion of the trail, as well as an `alpha` and `delay`.**
2. **In `touchesMoved:` calculate change in the position of the user touch and generate a new subpath based on that, then wrap it in the custom object.**
3. **Draw all the subpaths in the `-drawRect:` method, with their given alphas.**
4. **Setup a `CADisplayLink` to update the alphas and delays of the subpaths.**

So first of all, let's define our custom object...

```
/// Represents a small portion of a trail. 
@interface trailSubPath : NSObject

/// The subpath of the trail.
@property (nonatomic) CGPathRef path;

/// The alpha of this section.
@property (nonatomic) CGFloat alpha;

/// The delay before the subpath fades
@property (nonatomic) CGFloat delay;

@end
```

Let's also give it a convenience initialiser to make it look slick later on...

```
@implementation trailSubPath

+(instancetype) subPathWithPath:(CGPathRef)path alpha:(CGFloat)alpha delay:(CGFloat)delay {
    trailSubPath* subpath = [[self alloc] init];
    subpath.path = path;
    subpath.alpha = alpha;
    subpath.delay = delay;
    return subpath;
}

@end
```

Let's also define some constants at the top of your `UIView` **(make a subclass if you haven't already, as we're going to be drawing with `-drawRect:`)**

```
/// How long before a subpath starts to fade.
static CGFloat const pathFadeDelay = 5.0;

/// How long the fading of the subpath goes on for.
static CGFloat const pathFadeDuration = 1.0;

/// The stroke width of the path.
static CGFloat const pathStrokeWidth = 3.0;
```

In your `UIView`, you are going to want to store an `NSMutableArray` of your `trailSubPath` objects, as well as some other variables that we'll need later.

I decided the use a `CADisplayLink` to handle the updates to the `trailSubPath` objects. This way, the code will run at the same speed on all devices (at the cost of a lower FPS on slower devices).

```
@implementation view {

    UIColor* trailColor; // The stroke color of the trail
    NSMutableArray* trailSubPaths; // The array of trailSubPaths

    CGPoint lastPoint; // Last point the user touched
    BOOL touchedDown; // Whether the user is touching the screen

    CADisplayLink* displayLink; // A display link in order to allow the code to run at the same speed on different devices
}
```

In the `-initWithFrame:` method, we're going to do some basic setup...

```
-(instancetype) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {

        trailSubPaths = [NSMutableArray array];
        trailColor = [UIColor redColor];

        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Now let's setup the `UIResponder` touch methods...

```
-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    lastPoint = [[[event allTouches] anyObject] locationInView:self];
    touchedDown = YES;

    [displayLink invalidate]; // In case it's already running.
    displayLink = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(displayLinkDidFire)];
    [displayLink addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
}

-(void) touchesMoved:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if (touchedDown) {

        CGPoint p = [[[event allTouches] anyObject] locationInView:self];

        CGMutablePathRef mutablePath = CGPathCreateMutable(); // Create a new subpath
        CGPathMoveToPoint(mutablePath, nil, lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(mutablePath, nil, p.x, p.y);

        // Create new subpath object
        [trailSubPaths addObject:[trailSubPath subPathWithPath:CGPathCreateCopy(mutablePath) alpha:1.0 delay:pathFadeDelay]];

        CGPathRelease(mutablePath);

        lastPoint = p;
    }
}

-(void) touchesEnded:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    touchedDown = NO;
}

-(void) touchesCancelled:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [self touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

Nothing too complicated there, it just calculates the change in position of the touch on `-touchesMoved:` and generates a new straight line subpath based on this. This is then wrapped in our `trailSubPath` and added to the array.

Now, we need to setup the logic in the `CADisplayLink` update method. This will just calculate the change in alphas and delays of the subpaths and remove any subpaths that have already faded out:

```
-(void) displayLinkDidFire {

    // Calculate change in alphas and delays.
    CGFloat deltaAlpha = displayLink.duration/pathFadeDuration;
    CGFloat deltaDelay = displayLink.duration;

    NSMutableArray* subpathsToRemove = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (trailSubPath* subpath in trailSubPaths) {

        if (subpath.delay > 0) subpath.delay -= deltaDelay;
        else subpath.alpha -= deltaAlpha;

        if (subpath.alpha < 0) { // Remove subpath
            [subpathsToRemove addObject:subpath];
            CGPathRelease(subpath.path);
        }
    }

    [trailSubPaths removeObjectsInArray:subpathsToRemove];

    // Cancel running if nothing else to do.
    if (([trailSubPaths count] == 0) && !touchedDown) [displayLink invalidate];
    else [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Then finally, we just want to override the `drawRect:` method in order to draw all our `trailSubPath` objects in Core Graphics:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(ctx, trailColor.CGColor);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, pathStrokeWidth);

    for (trailSubPath* subpath in trailSubPaths) {
        CGContextAddPath(ctx, subpath.path);
        CGContextSetAlpha(ctx, subpath.alpha);
        CGContextStrokePath(ctx);
    }

}
```

It looks like a lot of code, but I'm sure you already have half of it setup to draw your line at the moment!

**Just note that a simple way to make the trial fade based on length is to move the call to `setNeedsDisplay` in the `CADisplayLink` update method over to the `-touchesMoved:` method, and invalidate the display link on `-touchesEnded:`.**

Phew. It's over... longest answer I've ever done.

---

## Finished Result

[image: Le finished result]

**Full project: https://github.com/hamishknight/Fading-Trail-Path**

Comment: Can you make the bigger head and smaller tail like this? https://github.com/angelXwind/iSwipe/raw/master/img/animate.gif

Comment: @TomSawyer Sure, you can just vary the line width for each line segment to create that effect. [See here](https://github.com/angelXwind/iSwipe/blob/master/src/ISScribbleView.m) for an example from the open source project the gif you linked to came from. (I know I commented this one of your now deleted posts, I'm leaving it here for reference).